# Notepad++, search for a string with a wild card between. except if (character) shows up between

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++, mysql

I have an issue where i need to remove a directory in a url that occurs many times in a mysql dump.

Here's the example.
"domain.com/unwanted/wp-content"

"unwanted" is not any specific word. sometimes it's "resource" and sometimes it's "events"

---

my issue is that when i do `(domain.com/).*?(/wp-content)`
I get matches like this:

"'domain.com/blah/blahblah'  some text here
more text here 'domain.com/wp-content'"

as an example, through regex is there a way i can use this search, and somehow include that if it detects the character ' before it reaches "wp-content" then it does not match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `(domain.com/)[^'"]*?(/wp-content)`

This will not include ' characters, so there will be no match.

Comment: awesome thank you. what if I want an or statement? to search for both ' and "

Comment: I am guessing this works. `(domain.com/)[^"^']*?(/wp-content)`

Comment: `(domain.com/)[^"']*?(/wp-content)` is enough. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @StephenM.Yantz The regular expression `[^abc]` matches any character except `a` or `b` or `c`. Your "guess" contains `[^"^']` which contains two of `^` and so it matches any character except `"` or `^` or `'`.